# Global installation of grunt.js fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I could install `gruntjs` locally using `npm install grunt`.

But when I'm trying to install it globally `npm install grunt -g`, i'm getting an error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-92.el5xen
npm ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lj
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.19
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt'
npm ERR! errno {}

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-92.el5xen
npm ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lj
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.19
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lj/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

With `sudo` I have error too:

```
npm ERR! Error: spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!     at errnoException (child_process.js:483:11)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:446:11)
npm ERR!     at child_process.js:342:9
npm ERR!     at Object.execFile (child_process.js:252:15)
npm ERR!     at uidNumber (/usr/lib/nodejs/uid-number/uid-number.js:33:17)
npm ERR!     at loadUid (/usr/lib/nodejs/npm/lib/npm.js:336:5)
npm ERR!     at Array.2 (/usr/lib/nodejs/bind-actor.js:15:8)
npm ERR!     at LOOP (/usr/lib/nodejs/chain.js:15:13)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/chain.js:18:7
npm ERR!     at setUser (/usr/lib/nodejs/npm/lib/npm.js:346:32)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-92.el5xen
npm ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lj
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.19
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lj/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

What could I do to install it?

P.S. It's possible that come rights for some folders is for `root:root`, not for my user. Cuz our admins installed VM that way...

Comment: Try `npm cache clean` first.

Comment: I've been used it. What should I do?

Comment: Seems like It depends on node installation type: local or global...

Answer (score 10):

I've had this problem too with grunt and bower

The solution I've found is in this article [NPM config](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html)

In your .npmrc you need to set the prefix path

```
prefix = /usr/local
```

or you can do it from terminal like this:

```
npm config set prefix "/usr/local"
```

This way node will know where to install them:

In npm 1.0, there are two ways to install things:

globally —- This drops modules in {prefix}/lib/node_modules, and puts executable files in {prefix}/bin, where {prefix} is usually something like /usr/local. It also installs man pages in {prefix}/share/man, if they’re supplied.

locally —- This installs your package in the current working directory. Node modules go in ./node_modules, executables go in ./node_modules/.bin/, and man pages aren’t installed at all.

Answer (score 4):

Try chowning the node_modules folder and then try to install again:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /path/to/node_modules/folder
```

Comment: This method worked for me, when I was told `sudo npm` wasn't a command

Answer (score 4):

Encountered same issue. The following works for me:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Answer (score 3):

try `sudo npm install -g grunt` ?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the option **--no-bin-links** works good. I tried everything and only this solved my problem. I was installing the Yeoman on ubuntu 12.04 and it was always returning the error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js'
```

Then, I did:

```
npm install -g --no-bin-links yo
```

=D

For more details https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2380